# Mysql - can I query the interval on an Event (Event-Scheduler)?

Tags: mysql, events, intervals

Is there a way to obtain the interval of an event?  I am modifying an event with different intervals, but I have other queries that depend on knowing how much time until the event is fired.

In order not to have to change each of those queries and operations, is there a way to find out the interval of a specific event and its current duration or its start time?

When I say Event I mean EVENT as in event-scheduler events.

```
CREATE EVENT event_Update ON SCHEDULE EVERY 2 MINUTE
DO
BEGIN
...
END
```

Comment: yes, but without any schemas or more details/examples, the best we can do it is say RTLM: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff

Comment: Im meaning EVENT not a generic event entry in a table.  ie http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html

Comment: `select * from mysql.event`, then.

Comment: perfect!  post as an answer?  so I can credit you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try getting the event details from the `mysql.event` table:

```
select * from mysql.event
```